# What layer would an Audio Player Service fall under in a an MVP system?

Tags: design-patterns, android, mvp

I'm trying to completely overhaul an app I wrote a while back that plays audio, and I'm learning how the MVP pattern of organization works, but I'm not sure how/where an audio playback service would fit in this design pattern, or how I could break out of this pattern without disrupting the benefits that come with it.

I'm working off of these tutorials/examples to get my head around the topic: 
[first example](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)|[second example](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)

I realize that the MVP pattern is not a complete system architecture, but I'm struggling to figure out how I can continue with the good practices set out in this patter with things like an audio play service. Or a download service, sense neither of those fall strictly under what I would think of data or presentation. If someone could point me in the right direction on this I would be very grateful.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be data? I mean, that's what they really are, right?

Comment: @RubberDuck I'm not really sure that it would fall under data. It has a UI component in it that it manages. But it's hard to say. At this point the whole MVP design pattern is still formulating in my head in terms of android.

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize the audio service had a UI component.

Comment: @RubberDuck it's just one of those notification controllers, so a user can play when the phone is locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the MV* patterns is primarily to provide separation of concerns between the UI and the rest of the system.  Your Audio Player Service, if it also includes the player, uses *the entire pattern.*  If it's just streaming data, it's the *model.*